# Ping between aws and gcp

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud, vpn, amazon-vpc

I have created a Site to Site VPN connection between VPC of Google cloud Platform and AWS in North Virginia region for both the VPCs. But the problem is I have been getting a very high ping and low bandwidth while communicating between the instances. Can any one tell me the reason for this?
[image showing the ping data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTdwZ.jpg)

The ping is very high considering they are in a very close region. Please help.

Comment: You do not have `very high ping` times. Your ping numbers will not affect your bandwidth except at the very high end. Your question has no facts, or configuration details. Specify what you need and what you are experiencing. As written, your question does not have an answer only opinions/suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that any VPN will be traversing the internet, so even though they are relatively close to each other there will be multiple hops before the instances are connected together.

Remember that from the instance it will need to route outside of AWS networks, then to any hops on the internet to GCP and finally routed to the instance and back again to return the response

In addition there is some variation in performance as the line will not be dedicated.

If you want dedicated performance, without traversing the internet you would need to look at [AWS Direct Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/). However, this might limit your project because of cost.

Comment: Actually I've been working on a small project. And AWS direct connect is very expensive to use. I just wanted to know Is the ping response usual or I've been doing something wrong.https://medium.com/@sachinkagarwal/public-cloud-inter-region-network-latency-as-heat-maps-134e22a5ff19.... I read this article and it says the ping response should be 1ms between AWS us east1 and GCP us east 4. But my response is very poor compared to this.

Comment: Ah thats fine, the big point is its not dedicated and its over the internet so always some variability to response times. Also worth looking at instance types. Newer generations may be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple reason behind the cause :
1) verify gcp network performance by gcping 
2) verify the tcp size and rtt for bandwidth 
3) verify with iperf or tcpdump for throughput

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/network-throughput

Comment: I have used iperf test and it shows a bandwidth of 230 Mbps. I just wanted to know that. Is this the maximum bandwidth and ping response that we can get or am I missing some parts because of which it is working slow. I have set up the connection using Site-to-site vpn connection between the two VPC networks. I have done a similar test between AWS and Azure as well. For AWS azure the ping response was 3ms and max. bandwidth from iperf was 650Mbps.

Comment: Have you tried to run a test network by creating two vpc network in gcp and set vpn connecting in-between and check the response time of ping and bandwidth. If the results are different then we need to check the configuration setting of gateways and vpn connections in between the gcp and aws

Comment: Isn't that done through VPC peering? Haven't tried that by VPN.

Comment: No its different way of testing vpn connection bandwidth , follow steps as follow :1) create two vpc networks, 2) create instance in both vpcs 3) create routers on both vpc  4) create classic or ha vpns by connecting both vpns , make sure you take care of the regions while creating it as it should all lie in same regions

Answer (score 1):

One of the many limits to TCP throughout is:

Throughput <= EffectiveWindowSize / RoundTripTime

If your goal is indeed higher throughput, then you can consider tweaking the TCP window size limits.  The default TCP window size under Linux is ~3MB.  However, there is more to EffectiveWindowSize than that.  There is also the congestion window, which will depend on factors such as packet losses and congestion control heuristics being used (eg cubic vs bbr).

As far as sanity checking the ping RTTs you are seeing, you can compare with ping times you see between an instance in AWS us-east-1 and GCP us-east4 when you are not using a VPN.